# Selecting Variadic Type with Runtime Index using Lookup Table

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Consider a variadic pack of types. It's possible to select and use one of those types indexed by a runtime value using a recursive indexing function and a lambda with an `auto` parameter as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

template<typename T> 
struct identity { using type = T; };

template<typename ... Cs>
struct variadic
{  
    template<size_t N>
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Cs ...>>;

    template<typename F, size_t I = 0>
    static void identify(size_t index, F action)
    {
        if (index == I)
        {
            std::invoke(action, identity<type<I>>());
            return;
        }

        if constexpr (I < (sizeof...(Cs) - 1))
        {
            identify<F, I + 1>(index, action);
            return;
        }

        throw std::runtime_error("failed to identify type");
    }
};

struct s_a { void speak() { std::cout << "s_a" << std::endl; } };
struct s_b { void speak() { std::cout << "s_b" << std::endl; } };
struct s_c { void speak() { std::cout << "s_c" << std::endl; } };
struct s_d { void speak() { std::cout << "s_d" << std::endl; } };
struct s_e { void speak() { std::cout << "s_e" << std::endl; } };
struct s_f { void speak() { std::cout << "s_f" << std::endl; } };

void speak(size_t index)
{
    variadic<s_a, s_b, s_c, s_d, s_e, s_f>::identify(index, [](auto id)
    {
        using state_type = typename decltype(id)::type;
        state_type().speak();
    });
}
```

This approach compile-time generates a sequence of if statements which, [under the hood](https://godbolt.org/z/HnS0vQ), resolve into a number of branches. I imagine after a certain point this would degenerate into a branch misprediction roadblock.

Is there a way to achieve this same behavior in a way that instead generates a lookup table (essentially a vtable) under the hood, similar to how `std::visit` works?

Comment: If you want something that works like `std::visit`, it should be possible to implement this in terms of a variant of tag types and use `visit` as the main part of the implementation.

Comment: I started going down that road. I could make a variant of `identity<T>`s above but it had to be populated with something in order to learn its type information. There's no variant constructor I'm aware of that takes a runtime index, so that type had to be decided at compile-time, which goes right back to the branching identifier function above.

In a way you could formulate this question as that, so "can you construct a variant that's type-differentiated by a runtime index?".

Comment: Ah, I see. It's unfortunate that it has this kind of optimized machinery and doesn't expose it except for about one limited use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "simple" way is to build an array of function pointers:

```
template<typename F>
static void identify(size_t index, F action) {
    // handle case when index > sizeof...(Cs)

    using FPtr = void(*)(F&);
    static constexpr FPtr table[] = {
        +[](F& action){ action(identity<type<Cs>>()) }...
    };
    table[index](action);
}
```

Some compilers might not like expanding a lambda like that, so you can make a real function:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
static void _apply(F& action) {
    action(identity<type<T>>());
}

template<typename F>
static void identify(size_t index, F action) {
    // handle case when index > sizeof...(Cs)

    using FPtr = void(*)(F&);
    static constexpr FPtr table[] = { _apply<Cs, F>... };
    table[index](action);
}
```

---

But optimizers tend to be pretty bad at inlining function pointers like this. `variant` implementations used to look like the above, but are moving away from it.

If you really want to go all out, you'll have to write a recursive switch... [Michael Park](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2019/01/22/variant-visitation-v2/) gives a good explanation of that, it's fairly complex.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like it's still using the recursive branching approach, but unrolling it in 32-case increments? I'll give both approaches a shot.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's an implementation of Michael Park's unrolled switch approach, linked by Barry.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

template<typename T> 
struct identity { using type = T; };

template<size_t I, typename ... Cs>
using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Cs ...>>;

template<bool Valid, typename ... Cs>
struct dispatcher;

template<typename ... Cs>
struct dispatcher<false, Cs ...> 
{
    template<size_t I, typename F>
    constexpr static void case_(F) 
    { 
        static_assert(I >= sizeof...(Cs));
        __builtin_unreachable(); 
    }

    template<size_t B, typename F>
    constexpr static void next_(size_t, F) 
    { 
        static_assert(B >= sizeof...(Cs));
        __builtin_unreachable(); 
    }
};

template<typename ... Cs>
struct dispatcher<true, Cs ...>
{
    template<size_t I, typename F>
    constexpr static void case_(F action) 
    { 
        static_assert(I < sizeof...(Cs));
        std::invoke(action, identity<type<I, Cs ...>>()); 
    }

    template<size_t B, typename F>
    constexpr static void next_(size_t index, F action)
    {
        constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Cs);

        switch (index) 
        {
        case B +  0: dispatcher<(B +  0 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  0>(action); break;
        case B +  1: dispatcher<(B +  1 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  1>(action); break;
        case B +  2: dispatcher<(B +  2 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  2>(action); break;
        case B +  3: dispatcher<(B +  3 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  3>(action); break;    
        case B +  4: dispatcher<(B +  4 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  4>(action); break;
        case B +  5: dispatcher<(B +  5 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  5>(action); break;
        case B +  6: dispatcher<(B +  6 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  6>(action); break;
        case B +  7: dispatcher<(B +  7 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  7>(action); break;    
        case B +  8: dispatcher<(B +  8 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  8>(action); break;
        case B +  9: dispatcher<(B +  9 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B +  9>(action); break;
        case B + 10: dispatcher<(B + 10 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 10>(action); break;
        case B + 11: dispatcher<(B + 11 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 11>(action); break;
        case B + 12: dispatcher<(B + 12 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 12>(action); break;
        case B + 13: dispatcher<(B + 13 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 13>(action); break;    
        case B + 14: dispatcher<(B + 14 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 14>(action); break;
        case B + 15: dispatcher<(B + 15 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 15>(action); break;
        case B + 16: dispatcher<(B + 16 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 16>(action); break;
        case B + 17: dispatcher<(B + 17 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 17>(action); break;    
        case B + 18: dispatcher<(B + 18 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 18>(action); break;
        case B + 19: dispatcher<(B + 19 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 19>(action); break;
        case B + 20: dispatcher<(B + 20 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 20>(action); break;
        case B + 21: dispatcher<(B + 21 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 21>(action); break;
        case B + 22: dispatcher<(B + 22 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 22>(action); break;
        case B + 23: dispatcher<(B + 23 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 23>(action); break;    
        case B + 24: dispatcher<(B + 24 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 24>(action); break;
        case B + 25: dispatcher<(B + 25 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 25>(action); break;
        case B + 26: dispatcher<(B + 26 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 26>(action); break;
        case B + 27: dispatcher<(B + 27 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 27>(action); break;    
        case B + 28: dispatcher<(B + 28 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 28>(action); break;
        case B + 29: dispatcher<(B + 29 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 29>(action); break;
        case B + 30: dispatcher<(B + 30 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 30>(action); break;
        case B + 31: dispatcher<(B + 31 < size), Cs ...>::template case_<B + 31>(action); break;
        default:     dispatcher<(B + 32 < size), Cs ...>::template next_<B + 32>(index, action); break;
        }
    }
};

template<typename ... Cs>
struct variadic
{  
    template <typename F>
    constexpr static void identify(size_t index, F action) 
    {
        constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Cs);
        if (index >= size)
            throw std::out_of_range("type index out of bounds");
        dispatcher<(0 < size), Cs ...>::template next_<0>(index, action);
    }
};

struct s_a { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_a" << std::endl; } };
struct s_b { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_b" << std::endl; } };
struct s_c { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_c" << std::endl; } };
struct s_d { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_d" << std::endl; } };
struct s_e { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_e" << std::endl; } };
struct s_f { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_f" << std::endl; } };

void speak(size_t index)
{
    variadic<s_a, s_b, s_c, s_d, s_e, s_f>::identify(index, [](auto id)
    {
        using state_type = typename decltype(id)::type;
        std::invoke(state_type());
    });
}
```

And for the sake of completeness, here's a version of the function pointer approach which, as advertised, does not optimize very well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

template<typename T> 
struct identity { using type = T; };

template<size_t I, typename ... Cs>
using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Cs ...>>;

template<typename ... Cs>
struct variadic
{  
    template <typename T, typename F>
    static void _apply(F& action) 
    {
        action(identity<T>());
    }

    template<typename F>
    static void identify(size_t index, F action) 
    {
        constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(Cs);
        if (index >= size)
            throw std::out_of_range("type index out of bounds");

        using func_ptr = void(*)(F&);
        static constexpr func_ptr table[] = { _apply<Cs, F>... };
        table[index](action);
    }
};

struct s_a { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_a" << std::endl; } };
struct s_b { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_b" << std::endl; } };
struct s_c { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_c" << std::endl; } };
struct s_d { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_d" << std::endl; } };
struct s_e { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_e" << std::endl; } };
struct s_f { void operator()() { std::cout << "s_f" << std::endl; } };

void speak(size_t index)
{
    variadic<s_a, s_b, s_c, s_d, s_e, s_f>::identify(index, [](auto id)
    {
        using state_type = typename decltype(id)::type;
        std::invoke(state_type());
    });
}
```

The unrolled switch approach looks like a winner in terms of optimization, and will be what I likely end up using.